# Connecting React Native to firebase gives me error

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to connect my react-native to firebase but it give's me an error. What can be the possible solution to this error. When I issue the command react-native run-android gives me this error

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugResValues'.
> Failed to create C:\Users\**\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Main\NativeFirebase\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugResValues'.
> Failed to create C:\Users\\***\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Main\NativeFirebase\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the project folder there is a folder called 'android' you must open it with Android Studio and run the project in your emulator, this will make you install the missing or necessary packages.
The problem is with SDK packages specifically the gradle will update you.

"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0."

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the build folder in your `android/app` directory and re-run the project again.